# What does it mean if a chip has additional engraving?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor

I have sold some microcontrollers. They are labelled 72F924 BK6T3 (best seen on the left chip), so it should be a 8-bit Microcontroller 8 MHz 32kB flash 1 kB RAM, but the chip is also engraved with DFS60A V03 (best seen on the right chip.)

The buyer complains that he can't use the chip. Why would that be? What does it mean if a chip has been engraved like that?

[image: Image of the ICs in question]

Comment: My guess is that they have already been programmed, thus the engraving.

Comment: Or they're (bad) fakes which have been put in the supply chain.

Comment: DFS60A could be a SICK incremental encoder. And V03 the version, perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/549967/STMicroelectronics/ST72F324/1) (sorry can't find it on the ST webpage) you could order the controller with a "Special Marking", which would be 7 characters for LQFP-32 and up to 10 characters for other packages.

There are no details how the marking would be carried out or how it would look like.

As you have the LQFP-32 package and the marking contains 9 characters, we can at least conclude that the marking was not done by ST, but in a process afterwards.

It's pretty common to let someone program a controller before it is mounted on a PCB. So this could well be a marking which is carried out in that step, to prevent accidental misuse of the programmed controller (how would you distinguish it on the production line?).

Answer (score 4):

That’s a legitimate question, and the buyer is right. Those are parts marked by a value-added vendor after programming. They would be acceptable for hobby use, but most QA rules and production good practices would exclude such parts. In other words: they are not usable in a business setting.

Comment: True. 'Usable' might become a bit more flexible if the lead times are 73 weeks on the nice parts though.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  LOL   All I can say is "Yep"....

Answer (score 2):

They look like pre-programmed MCUs. The engraved text seems to be containing the software name and version.

There are several situations where the MCUs need to be programmed even before assembly, such as:

- Size-limited applications where there's no space for on-board programming pins.
- Very high-volume productions for which the manufacturer do not want to lose time with programming (Even ST can program the hex file you provided during the production of the chip).

Some manufacturers prefer to put a label containing a barcode or QR code or some text. If the environment is harsh enough to damage the label the manufacturer may have preferred a permanent way.

---

In the past one of the companies I worked for purchased some STM8 MCUs for an extremely low price from a very well known distributor (projectile of a bow). We first suspected that the MCUs would be fake but later on learned that they are pre-programmed by ST, sent to the customer and returned to the distributor by the customer. I remember some strange coding/marking on it but possibly they could be the code that Arsenal talked about. It wasn't engraving but ST's original (laser?) marking.